# How to push UIViewController in UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to push a view from the `UITabBarControler`. My app hierarchy looks like this:

> UINavigationController -> UIView -> UITabBarController

I have a `UITabBarController` with 3 tabs.  On the first tab, I have added a `UITableView`.  How can I make it so that the selection of a cell in the table pushes to another view without navigating from the tab control?

Comment: are you refering to push a detail view from tableview which is inside a tab bar?

Comment: ya exact-ally but tab bar already in navigation control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want a navigation-controller type push inside the tab bar interface, you need a navigation interface *inside* the tab bar interface.

Your simplest solution, though, might be to reconsider your interface.

Comment: Any tutorial or part of code in which using that code i can done my job

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is the arrange you are doing.

You are using `UINavigationController -> UIView -> UITabBarController`, so `UITabBarController` is a subview of the `UINavigationController`. When you navigate, the view you are popping is FROM THE NAVIGATION CONTROLLER, so ALL its content (including the `UITabBarController`) will disappear.

You structure needs to be like this:

`UITabBarController -> UINavigationController -> UIView`, which means one `UINavigationController` per every tab that needs it.

For example, if you need to use push inside two tabs, the structure should be like this:

`UITabBarController`

```
|  --> UINavigationController 1 --> UIView 1 --> (push segue) --> UIView 1B

|  --> UINavigationController 2 --> UIView 2 --> (push segue) --> UIView 2B
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

[How to handle UINavigationControllers and UITabBarControllers iOS 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400827/how-to-handle-uinavigationcontrollers-and-uitabbarcontrollers-ios-6-1/15454094#15454094)

That's a more complicated version, but take a look at the Tab Bar Controller and it's relationship with it's contained viewControllers.

Basically you don't want your tabBarController to be embedded in that Nav Controller. Instead, each contained viewController that wants to push on should be embedded in it's own Nav Controller. So in your case you would at least do that for your first tab's tableViewController.