# How to open new view controller after click button?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I added one `ViewController` to my project and created one class.
After I bind this class to my `ViewController`.

In another controller I have method:

`- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {
  // How here I can do redirect to controller`ViewController
`}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing viewController on Button Click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814752/changing-viewcontroller-on-button-click)

Comment: Do some research before you post a question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two ways to push view controllers in the application.

**1) by Segue**

**2) By View controller identifier**

1) By Segue :

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:"SegueIdentifier" sender:self];
```

2) By View controller identifier :

```
Yourclassname *gotoYourClass = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerIdentifier"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:gotoYourClass animated:YES];
```

Comment: I must to set `SegueIdentifier` in properties in ViewController in storyboard?

Comment: yes you have to select segue from the storyboard and then set the identifier Utilities menu. @Balabama

Comment: it does not work, may be I need to connnect controllers in storeboad?

Comment: you need to crate another view controller.

Comment: I have created and set for it identificator `SegueIdentifier`

Comment: This post is a duplicate, so stop posting repetitive stuff

Comment: Second way "By View controller identifier" helped me, i can open View escaping UITabBarController segue

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {
 ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
 [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil]; }
```

Comment: This post is a duplicate, so stop posting repetitive stuff

Comment: I'm new here so I didn't realize that

Answer (score 1):

In the storyboard give your view controller an identifier (under the Attributes Inspector) then use the following code, to bring that view forward.

**IF YOU WANT TO USE PUSH THEN USE THIS CODE**

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"STORYBOARDNAME" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VIEWCONTROLLERIDENTIFIER"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animeted:YES];
```

**IF YOU WANT TO PRESENT THEN USE THIS CODE**

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"STORYBOARDNAME" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VIEWCONTROLLERIDENTIFIER"];
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

**Note:** In UIViewController please enter your view controller name which you want to push into another view.

Comment: This post is a duplicate, so stop posting repetitive stuff

Comment: this is not repetitive stuff.according to me  the code is the same for pushing one view to another view using storyboard so....

Answer (score 1):

If you want to comeback to the current ViewController later then use **Navigation ViewController** or else just use the **presentedViewController of self**(your current viewController)- no going back business, like they have previously illustrated.

For a simple block of execution(demo or practice) it's all the same but for a project application it completely matters to make the correct choice.

Comment: One more tip is avoid segues to perform transition between view controllers as much as possible and prefer to keep the transition programmatically implemented - easy to modify and better control over the actions taking place.