# Navigate to specific view controller from NotificationContent Extension - iOS

Tags: apple-push-notifications, unnotificationscontentextension

I have implemented custom UI for push notification using Notification Content Extension. I have added an "View" action as below

```
let navigateAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "ActionNotification", title: "View", options: [])  

let deafultCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier:
    "myNotifService", actions: [navigateAction], intentIdentifiers:[], options: [])
```

Now, in Content Extension's class - NotificationViewController

```
func didReceive(_ response: UNNotificationResponse, completionHandler completion:(UNNotificationContentExtensionResponseOption) -> Void) {
   if response.actionIdentifier == "ActionNotification" {
       // HERE I NEED TO NAVIGATE TO SPECIFIC VIEW CONTROLLER
   }
   completion(.dismiss)
}
```

Whenever I click on "View" button, above function is triggered but I need to navigate to specific screen from here. Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: Yes @Odwori, I am using storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

for swift try

```
let viewController = MyViewController(nibName: "MyNextViewController", bundle: nil)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

or for normal transition

```
    next:MyViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyViewViewController") as!  MyViewViewController  
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(next, animated: true)
```

for objective-c try

[Try this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34655473/how-to-open-new-view-controller-after-click-button)

Comment: as!  MyViewViewController - Here its showing error when I replace with my view controllers "use of undeclared type "ABCController".
I guess this is not the way to navigate form a ContentExtension. Thank you for your reply @Odwori.